# Stream management after Environment.exit() invocation

Tags: c#, filestream, using, try-catch-finally

I was searching in `StackOverflow` about `try-finally` and `using` blocks and what are the best practices on using them.
I read in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304308/try-catch-finally-question) that if your application is terminated abruptly by killing the process, a `finally` block will **not** get executed.

I was wondering, does the same apply to the `using` blocks? Will for example a stream get closed if a `Environment.exit()` call occurs inside the `using` block?:

```
//....
using (FileStream fsSource1 = new FileStream(pathSource,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  //Use the stream here
  Environment.exit();
}
```

As a second thought on it, and knowing that `CLR` *Garbage Collector* will probably take care of the stream objects if not closed properly in the program calls, is it considered necessary to close a stream in code, if the program gets terminated for sure after the completion of the stream usage?

For example, is there any practical difference between:

```
//....
using (FileStream fsSource1 = new FileStream(pathSource,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  //Use the stream here
}
Environment.exit();
```

And:

```
//....
FileStream fsSource1 = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
//Use the stream here
Environment.exit();
```

Or even the example mentioned before?

Comment: [Calling Environment.Exit() Within a Using Block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13165895)

Comment: Ok, this is very helpful, but the question has 2 parts: first of all, what happens if I call the `Environment.Exit()` inside a using block, and second and most important, what are the differences and if there is any point on using such finalization if the program is about to terminate immediately after use.

Comment: Why would you *not* dispose of it correctly? That's just good practice - dispose of your resources as soon as you no longer need them. What if you decide one day to expand your application and forget about the fact that you haven't disposed of that particular resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *shouldn't* make a difference in the specific case of FileStream, modulo a tricky corner case when you used its BeginWrite() method.  Its finalizer attempts to complete writing any unwritten data still present in its internal buffer.  This is however not generally true, it **will** make a difference if you use StreamWriter for example.

What you are leaving up to the .NET Framework to decide is whether you truly meant to jerk the floor mat and seize writing the file.  Or whether it should make a last-gasp attempt to flush any unwritten data.  The outcome in the case of StreamWriter will tend to be an unpleasant one, non-zero odds that *something* is going to fall over when it tries to read a half-written file.

Always be explicit, if you want to make sure this does not happen then it is up to you to ensure that you properly called the Close() or Dispose() method.  Or delete the file.